# If a series converges absolutely, then any sub-series also converges absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a series converges absolutely, then any sub-series also converges absolutely.

1) is it true?
2) is there a simple "one line" argument to prove it?

Comment: Partial sums (of the absolute values) are bounded non-decreasing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the “subseries” has general term $(a_{n_k})$, then for the $k$-th partial sum of the subseries we have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k|a_{n_i}|\le\sum_{i=0}^{n_k}|a_i|\le\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|a_i|
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** The answer is yes, since for any sub series $\sum  u_{\phi(n)}$, you may write
$$
\sum\left|  u_{\phi(n)}\right|\leq  \sum\left| u_{n}\right|.
$$

Comment: This is unclear to me; what are the bounds of the sums? If they're infinite, this is circular, and if they're finite, it would seem to hinge on $u_n$ being decreasing, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Meelo Let's take it as finite sums. If the RHS converges, then the LHS converges (the partial sum is increasing and bounded): this gives an answer the question in the title.